# Is testability and mockability really that important in web development?

Tags: design-patterns, unit-testing, laravel

I'm reading [this](http://culttt.com/2013/04/29/getting-started-with-laravel-4/) series on Laravel, and it's in great depth dealing with making everything testable, using *Repository* instead of just using the *Models*, using *Dependency Injection* and other obscure techniques.

I've got a feeling that adding all this extra complexity in the name of Testability may not be the right thing. Writing unit tests for everything, that sounds plain silly.

I have used Laravel before, without all this "testability" stuff, and it just worked.

Is "testability" worth the effort and making code harder to understand?

(note that I'm posting here instead of StackOverflow, for this is kind of opinion based. I hope I won't be frowned upon for asking it.)

Comment: Some applications benefit from automated testing, you grant that? Then please explain why the same benefits don't apply to web development.

Comment: I'm about to start on a rather large project, but I'm deciding if I really want to add all this testability crap or write it clean. I'm not really seeing benefits of writing overcomplicated code just for this reason.

Comment: "testability" worth the effort and making code harder to understand? HARDLY! Unit tests help you document "what the code does"!

Comment: @HenryAloni but I have comments for this, there's PhpDoc that can describe each method.

Comment: What I meant was this : Although a PHPDoc can describe your API, it does not prove that the API actually "does what it was planned to do". A unit test, on the other hand, while supplying loose description - it supplies a core usage example. Examples make it easier to understand APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a fair amount of debate in terms of when, where, and how to test an application of X complexity. And a fair amount of political zeal on all sides. In my own experience, I've been on a lot of projects that were small and simple, arguably requiring little automated testing. And truthfully, I developed with nearly zero automated testing and horrendously untestable code for 10+ years with no *visible* repercussions.

As time went on, I found that the complexity in these "simple" applications slowly grew. And as complexity grows, you'll more often track bugs to minute changes to a methods functioning that were benign seeming at the time. Or you'll find team members using a method wrong because it breaks a convention or doesn't match their expectations.

If you have high code coverage, these concerns are far lessened. And if you test *first*, you're more likely to write testable code that behaves as others would expect. You're starting with testable expectations; you're not contorting tests to match untestable code or letting expectations be biased by your implementation ideas. You're writing code to pass a *meaningful test*. (Make your tests meaningful.)

**Testability** is just a natural concern if you want to test. And you *do* want to test! The question is whether you want to automate that testing. (And you do.) Most complex applications benefit greatly from automated testing. Simple ones benefit too. And if you're tempted to forgo the testing because it adds more complexity than is initially inherent to the application, remember that most applications eventually become complex anyway.

---

In the interest of full disclosure, I've actually only been attempting to make my code more test-driven and *more highly testable* quite recently. That said, the number of bugs my automated tests have revealed and prevented is significant. My confidence in the highly-covered code has exponentially increased. My code has gotten prettier. And I've been more continuously motivated to write and satisfied with the successful outcome of every line of of code since I transitioned.

... I feel a bit like a brain-washed cult-member. But, it's all true!

Comment: Alright, so I suppose there is some point, but is it worth sacrificing proper OOP structure? What I see is making interfaces for everything just to make it mockable. Dependency injection, huge complication just to make the class testable...

Comment: @MightyPork Well, not for everything. And it is up to you (or your lead developer, or your architect) to decide whether it's worth it. You basically do that by defining quality goals and maybe come to the conclusion testability is a top 5 criteria (or you do not test at all, because you implement a static webpage). BTW: when writing unit-tests you often unveil caveats in your code like bad model-structure, so maybe your model wasn't that good after all.

Comment: I can't tell you from personal experience what it takes for something to *really* be testable, particularly in Laravel. You read the wiki's on some of the patterns and policies and you'll see as many cons as pros for each pattern. Maybe I'll come back in a year evangelizing those testability patterns - for now, I'd say if you *tend* to write your tests first, and if you're tests are aimed at verifying small amounts of code, you'll naturally write testable code. And much of it will adhere to the testability "rules." You can't verify a new conditional in a method you can't target it specifically